# Map two classes to one table using JPA to speed up spring security UserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I want to make a secured restful service using Spring, JPA and Hibernate.

Each endpoint must be secured and I use spring security for that purpose using a specific UserDetailsService as describe in the spring security documentation : 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#userdetailsservice-implementations

Here the point : as each request will be authentified, it means that for each request, my UserDetailsService will load a user form my database and need to get its password and its roles.

The default JdbcDaoImpl use 2 requests to find a user and its roles. 
I don't use it because :

- I want to have my users' Id in a UserDetails object as my business controller use it.
- I want that my users are loaded with only one request

My user business object look like :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "aa_user")
public class User
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   Long id;

   @NotNull
   @Column(unique = true)
   protected String login;

   protected String password;

   @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Role.class)
   protected List<Role> roles;

   //getter/setter
}
```

And my repository :

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>
{
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u JOIN FETCH u.roles where u.login = :login")
    User findByLogin(@Param("login") String login);
}
```

My UserDetailsService :

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
{
    User user = null;
    try
    {
        user = userRepository.findByLogin(username);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Can't find username: " + username);
    }
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Can't find username: " + username);
    }

    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = new UserDetailsImpl(user);

    return userDetails;
}
```

I have a lot of User subclasses (like Seller, ...) which have associations to other objects fetch eagerly for business purpose and with this implementation, the `userRepository.findByLogin(username)` make something like 3 or more heavy joins to give me the right full fetch user object (which is "normal" of course), but I only want one light query with only the User's field initialized.

According to this question : 
[Avoiding outer joins across tables when using joined inheritance with Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541129/avoiding-outer-joins-across-tables-when-using-joined-inheritance-with-spring-dat) what I want to do seems complicated, but I found that I could use `@Polymorphism` Hibernate annotation with `PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT` : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18358863/1661338

`@Polymorphism` is not JPA compliant and brake parts of my business logic or need that I refactor a lot of query.

To avoid that, I add a second class mapped on the same Table :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "aa_user")
public class LightUser implements SimpleUser
{  
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   Long id;

   @NotNull
   @Column(unique = true)
   protected String login;

   protected String password;

   @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Role.class)
   protected List<Role> roles;

   //getter
}
```

And my repository :

```
public interface LightUserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>
{
    @Query("SELECT u FROM LightUser u JOIN FETCH u.roles where u.login = :login")
    LightUser findByLogin(@Param("login") String login);
}
```

Both `User`and `LightUser` implements the same `SimpleUser` interface with all getter needed for my `UserDetailsImpl`.

Now, `lightUserRepository.findByLogin(username)` make the smartest query possible and get only what I want.

I still have questions :

- Is it JPA compliant ?
- `hbm2ddl.SchemaExport` work but try to put 2 times the same foreign key between table `aa_user` and role table. How to avoid that ?
- It could be less painful to write if I can make a query with the same behavior as `PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT`. Does anyone know if it's possible ?
- Can LightUser be "readOnly" object to avoid mistakes ?

Comment: Have you tried using LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN FETCH, to get lazy loading?

Comment: This join works perfectly as expected, the join I don't want were in User Subclasses not shown here

Comment: I believe the JPA version of `@Polymorphism` is `@Inheritance`. It allows you to use single-table or joined muti-table. Joined is known to have some performance issues. If you do single-table, then the table will have all fields and allow nulls in those fields, so you might loose some data integrity enforcement. Single table requires you specify a `@DiscriminatorColumn` on the parent object and a `@DiscriminatorValue` on the children that identifies which object JPA needs to build. More info here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

Comment: `@Polymorphism` and `@Inheritance` doesn't target the same goal :  
- `@Inheritance` as you explain change the way JPA store objects in DB and in fact have a performance impact, but doesn't prevent automatic polymorphism when objects are loaded from DB  
- `@Polymorphism` only apply to Hibernate and can prevent automatic polymorphism when objects are loaded from DB. See [this open question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17300157/1661338)  
  What I do is only use the [lightweight pattern](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/LightweightClass)