# Hibernate: Problems using PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT and InheritanceType.JOINED

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, joined-subclass

I'm trying to get some entities inheritance to behave as I understand the docs. Here is what I understand from [hibernate javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/PolymorphismType.html#EXPLICIT), [hibernate user guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-polymorphism), or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571629/hibernate-4-explicit-polymorphism-annotation-not-working):

Having this inheritance schema:

```
     Parent         <= @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    /      \
ChildA      ChildB  <= @Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
```

- When I query `Parent`, I get only data from the supertype.
- If I want to get data from a `Child` along with the supertype's one, I have to query the subtype directly.

I find very interresting the fact that I can store most commonly used fields into the supertype, so I can make big queries on the `Parent` without joins and smaller queries on the `Child`s.

The problem is that Hibernate keeps fetching `Child` with join when I query `Parent`:

```
select
    childb0_.id as id1_2_0_,
    childb0_1_.stringAttribute as stringAt2_2_0_,
    childb0_.intAttribute as intAttri1_1_0_
from
    ChildB childb0_
inner join
    Parent childb0_1_
        on childb0_.id=childb0_1_.id
where
    childb0_.id=?
```

And thus, either using Jpql or Criteria:

```
List<?> results = jpaApi.em()
    .createQuery("FROM Parent")
    .getResultList();
```

or

```
List<?> results = jpaApi.em()
    .unwrap(Session.class)
    .createCriteria(Parent.class)
    .list();
```

We made a [dummy project](https://github.com/stammw/hibernate-polymorphism-test) to illustrate and reproduce the problem.

I realize that this question might seem like a replicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277500/hibernate-polymorphism-explicit-annotation-doesnt-work), but why would PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT exist if hibernate does an IMPLICIT join either way ?

Comment: I found some other thread that relates to this question : [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277500/hibernate-polymorphism-explicit-annotation-doesnt-work) seems to agree with my opinion on how it should work, and  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541129/avoiding-outer-joins-across-tables-when-using-joined-inheritance-with-spring-dat?rq=1) says that EclipseLink v2.5.0 does the trick, i'll give it a try.

Comment: It's also possible to use a class mapped to the parent entity and that has no inheritance information. Like [this](https://github.com/stammw/hibernate-polymorphism-test/blob/28c32efade76609130093d55928ede5beed139b6/app/models/ParentShallow.java#L13) and [there](https://github.com/stammw/hibernate-polymorphism-test/blob/28c32efade76609130093d55928ede5beed139b6/test/models/TestDao.java#L50). This is not very clean but works and could be improved using a special hierarchy for `Parent`.